# How can I avoid press "Enter" during Java Sun (Oracle) 1.6 installation on Linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, java

It is quite easy to install java sun jdk 1.6.x using xxx.rpm.bin installer from java.com, but it forces you to press "Enter" for the license agreement during installation.  This is a problem for me as I need to create script to install java jdk automatically. Anyone know how to avoid this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The linux command "yes" can repeatedly press a key (default is y)

```
yes | ./jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin
```

Pretty simple, If you want it to just hit `<Enter>` do:

```
yes '' | ./jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin
```

See more at http://www.computerhope.com/unix/yes.htm

Answer (score 1):

I presume you already add executable attribute to the bin file:

```
echo | ./jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin
```

Or if is expecting Y,y or yes:

```
echo y | ./jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin
```

Now, just be patient and wait until the end.

Comment: While this will work if it is expecting one `<Enter>` or `y`, if it is expecting more than one you will need to use a command like `yes`.